# ExtendableEvent.waitUntil - is there any way to increase the frequency of retries?

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I'm building a pwa for a client that will list upcoming tasks for their employees. They will often be in areas with poor mobile service so the intention is that records are downloaded whenever they have data and then loaded locally from indexeddb.

My original intention was to use "periodic sync" until I realised that the maximum refresh time was once every 12 hours.

Next I moved onto regular background sync, with the js app sending a sync request to the service worker, and the service worker running the functionality on `ExtendableEvent.waitUntil` as in Google's background sync example:

```
self.addEventListener('sync', function(event) {
  if (event.tag == 'myFirstSync') {
    event.waitUntil(doSomeStuff());
  }
});
```

What I've found however is that `event.waitUntil` only seems to re-attempt the call every 5 minutes and I want a much faster refresh rate (more like every 30 seconds).

I kind of have 2 questions - first, is it possible to speed up the retry rate on `waitUntil`.

Perhaps more importantly, is this even a helpful strategy? It seems to me that my app could just repeatedly call the update function without even bothering the service worker. What advantage do I actually get from background sync?

Is there anything else in the pwa toolkit that would better suit my needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The benefit of (regular, "non-periodic") background sync is that the lifetime of the retries extend beyond the lifetime of your web app being open. Once the sync eventually succeeds, you could do something like show a notification (assuming the user has granted permission) that will take the user back to your web app to continue working.

Because this feature involves running code in the background, with the browser open but the web app potentially closed, there are limits imposed by the browser on how often the code will run. You can't increase the frequency of the retry attempts.

But you can definitely implement retry logic outside of the context of the service worker and background sync, by running code at the frequency you desire from within the context of your web app itself. But in that scenario, the retries will cease as soon as the user closes your web app.

Comment: Yes this does make sense. In my case, the users have the app open the whole time so I don't think I'll gain much by bouncing everything through background sync. Thanks for clarifying.